# How to emit signals from a class that can't inhert QObject?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a custom python interpreter.

Here is the code for the interpreter.py

```py
import sys
from io import StringIO, IncrementalNewlineDecoder
from code import InteractiveConsole
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from stream import NewLineIO

class PythonInterpreter(QObject, InteractiveConsole):
    output = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.l = {}
        InteractiveConsole.__init__(self, self.l)
        self.out = NewLineIO()
        self.out.output.connect(self.console)

    def write(self, data):
        self.output.emit(data)

    def runcode(self, codez):
        """
        Reimplementation to capture stdout and stderr
        """
        sys.stdout = self.out
        sys.stderr = self.out
        sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__
        result = InteractiveConsole.runcode(self, codez) # Own namespace :(
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
        #self.output.emit(self.out.getvalue()) # Send the output
        return result

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def console(self, string):
        self.output.emit(string)
```

To get the interpreter to send the output I had to create a custom `StreamIO` class that would emit from inside every time the `write()` method was called.

Here is stream.py

```py
from io import StringIO
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from signals import PrimitiveSignals


class NewLineIO(QObject, StringIO):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        StringIO.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.output = PrimitiveSignals()

    def write(self, s):
        print(s, file=sys.__stdout__)
        self.output.signal_str.emit(s)
```

However, for some reason, I can't instantiate QObject in `class NewLineIO`.

This is the traceback I get.

```
File "G:\Programming\Projects\AlphaDice\alpha_dice\main.py", line 9, in <module>
  from interpreters import PythonInterpreter
￼ File "G:\Programming\Projects\AlphaDice\alpha_dice\interpreters.py", line 5, in <module>
  from stream import NewLineIO
￼ File "G:\Programming\Projects\AlphaDice\alpha_dice\stream.py", line 17, in <module>
  class NewLineIO(QObject, TestLineIO):

builtins.TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

Removing QObject from the NewLineIO solves the problem temporarily, but I would no longer be able to connect `self.out` to `self.console`.

Is there a way I can make this code work?

Comment: what is PrimitiveSignals?

Comment: they are just a simple class that holds some pyqtSignals. So basically `signal_str = pyqtSignal(str)` pretty much. This is just in case I need to format anything in the future.

Comment: The NewLineIO class does not have to inherit from QObject, the PrimitiveSignals class should inherit from QObject

Comment: @eyllanesc it already does https://hastebin.com/opoyidisil.hs

Comment: You must call the parent constructor: `def __init__(self): QObject.__init__(self)`

Comment: `class PrimitiveSignals(QObject):
    signal_str = pyqtSignal(str)
    signal_int = pyqtSignal(int)
    signal_float = pyqtSignal(float)
    signal_list = pyqtSignal(list)
    signal_tuple = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    signal_dict = pyqtSignal(dict)
    signal_object = pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)`

Comment: see this: https://hastebin.com/dekivevece.py

Comment: @eyllanesc still the same error though, just re-ran the program

Comment: see this: https://hastebin.com/curiwononu.py

Comment: Do you want me to do this code: `self.out.output.connect(self.console)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145252/discussion-between-daegontaven-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classes containing the signals must inherit from QObject:

```
class PrimitiveSignals(QObject):
    signal_str = pyqtSignal(str)
    [...]
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
```

The NewLineIO class must not inherit from QObject so you can modify it to:

```
class NewLineIO(StringIO):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        StringIO.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.output = PrimitiveSignals()

    def write(self, s):
        print(s, file=sys.__stdout__)
        self.output.signal_str.emit(s)
```

`QObject` and its derived classes do not have the connect method, these have the signals. You must change:

```
self.out.output.connect(self.console)
```

to:

```
self.out.output.signal_str.connect(self.console)
```